# Is there any way we can configure hazelcast in master-slave architecture like redis with Spring boot

Tags: redis, hazelcast

Currently hazelcast is using cloud discovery for communication.
So if there are 4 kubernetes pods and each of them is having in-memory hazelcast. whenever hazelcast cache is updated in one of the pod, it gets updated in one of the other pod. but in case both of these pods get downscaled and get terminated, the data which is only in these 2 pods is lost. Can we have something like redis where we can provide server, port of the hazelcast cluster and it will be independent of kubernetes pod

Comment: Why do you think data is lost ? When a pod is shutdown the data is contains is divided amongst the remaining pods.

Comment: I am using in memory maps to store data. After upscale and then downscale scenario, I am getting null for few records when trying to fetch.

Comment: Can you post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?

Comment: What command do you use to downscale ? Do you get the same behaviour if you downscale by 1 twice, rather than by 2 once? What version of HZ ? What's in the Dockerfile ? Any pod shutting down will normally offload the data it has, resulting in no data loss. But the offload can be deactivated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the following [Blog Post](https://hazelcast.com/blog/how-to-scale-hazelcast-imdg-on-kubernetes/) ("Scale without Data Loss!" section) to read how to scale Hazelcast cluster on Kubernetes to avoid data loss.

Also, you can check the [official README of hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes) plugin. There is a [section dedicated to scaling there](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes#rolling-upgrade-and-scaling).

Comment: Actually, the problem is data loss is not just happening while scaling down. In a few of the cases, the abrupt shutdown of the node is also causing the data loss. So we decided to move hazelcast to separate cluster. But I am not sure how my spring boot would be able to connect to it.